# MSN Messenger Add-in

Tags: add-in, msn-messenger, windows-live-messenger

Q1. I read that Add-ins are no longer supported in MSN Messenger, on the other hand i see articles talking about how to change registery settings to enable Add-in option. I am not sure what is right.?

Q2. If Addin is supported then how do i write my own add-in using .net 3.5 ?
What Library/SDK i need.?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although add-ins are no longer supported, it does not mean that you cannot develop add-in. But it's discouraged by MS and can be a real pain (Poor or no documentation, API changes without notice, etc). Read the [Patchou blog](http://www.patchou.com/tag/messenger/) for more info (the developer of Messenger Plus)

The only extension supported by MS are Activities. More info at the [Windows Live Messenger Activity SDK Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751024.aspx)